# Sending mail using javamail api from IBM Websphere Application Server

Tags: java, websphere, jakarta-mail

How to send mail using gmail from IBM Websphere Application Server 7 using javamail 1.4 api  without using a certificate? I either get

> javax.mail.MessagingException:
>   Exception reading response;   nested
>   exception is:
>     javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   com.ibm.jsse2.util.g: PKIX path
>   building failed:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException:
>   PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not
>   build a valid CertPath.; internal
>   cause is: 
>     java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException:
>   The certificate issued by OU=Equifax
>   Secure Certificate Authority,
>   O=Equifax, C=US is not trusted;
>   internal cause is: 
>     java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException:
>   Certificate chaining error

or

> Must issue a STARTTLS command first
>   javamail

The same application works fine if I run it inside a main function in a java application. I have configured WAS mail sessions. Can someone please provide a working logic for the application and configuration in WAS for that?